# Estimation of mean and standard deviation when merging two observations

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

I've got following scenario:

I have two observations with $\mu$ unknown:

$$
X_a \sim N(\mu, \sigma_a), X_b \sim N(\mu, \sigma_b)
$$

Both are observation for the same quantity $X$, just measured with different systems. I want to estimate the parameters of $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ based on the two observation.

For that I took a basic MLE to estimate $\mu$:

$$
L = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2_a}} exp(\frac{-(x_a - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma_a^2}) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2_b}} exp(\frac{-(x_b - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma_b^2})
$$

This basically yields the equation of a weighted mean:
$$\mu = \frac{\sigma^2_a x_b + \sigma^2_b x_a}{\sigma^2_a + \sigma^2_b}$$

Now I want to calculate the standard deviation of $X$, but somehow I am not sure how to approach this. Can I just assume (based on $\operatorname{VAR}(Z) = \operatorname{VAR}(aY) = a^2 \operatorname{VAR}(Y)$), that:
$$
\sigma^2 = var = (\frac{\sigma^2_a}{\sigma^2_a + \sigma^2_b})^2 \sigma^2_b + (\frac{\sigma^2_b}{\sigma^2_a + \sigma^2_b})^2 \sigma^2_a
$$

Or am I mistaken about that?

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adapt to their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`. To get the proper font and spacing for an operator like $\operatorname{Var}$, use `\operatorname{Var}`. Frequently used functions such as `\exp` also have a shorthand command of their own.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. If I understand correctly, $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_b$ are known? What exactly is $\sigma$? You write that $X_a$ and $X_b$ are measurements of the same quantity $X$ with different systems. In what sense is this quantity a random variable? In case you mean something along the lines that $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_b$ are measuring uncertainties but $X$ "itself" also has an inherent uncertainty not caused by measurement, it seems you don't have any information about this uncertainty since your access to $X$ is solely through measurements with known uncertainties?

Comment: ok, in general I am trying to estimate the mean of the variable x, which is measured by different systems with different uncertainties. Since I know calculate the mean, I want to also know the uncertainty of my estimation.

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions. You know the variances of the measurements you're combining, so you can calculate the variance of your estimate for $\mu$. What's there to estimate? Are you just writing "estimate" when you mean "calculate"? Or is there some additional uncertainty that you haven't described yet?

Comment: sorry for the confusion you're right. I mean calculate instead of estimating

Comment: Please edit the question accordingly. People shouldn't have to read through the comments to understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ be independent Gaussian rvs s.t. $X_k\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma_k^2)$.

(1) We calculate the MLE of $\mu$: we set the first order condition and we obtain the estimator
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\ln(L(x_1,...,x_n;\mu))=\sum_{1\leq k \leq n}\frac{x_k-\mu}{\sigma_k^2}=0$$
$$\implies\hat{\mu}_{\textrm{MLE}}(X_1,...,X_n)=\sum_{1\leq k \leq n}\frac{X_k}{\sigma_k^2}\bigg/\sum_{1\leq k \leq n}\frac{1}{\sigma_k^2}$$
(2) Denote the denominator with $\gamma:=\sum_{1\leq k \leq n}\frac{1}{\sigma_k^2}$. We get, by independence
$$V[\hat{\mu}_{\textrm{MLE}}(X_1,...,X_n)]=\gamma^{-2}V\bigg[\sum_{1\leq k \leq n}\frac{X_k}{\sigma_k^2}\bigg]=\gamma^{-2}\sum_{1\leq k \leq n}\frac{\sigma_k^2}{\sigma_k^4}=\gamma^{-2}\gamma=\gamma^{-1}$$
(3) By using your case:
$$\frac{\sigma_a^4\sigma_b^2+\sigma_b^4\sigma_a^2}{(\sigma_a^2+\sigma_b^2)^2}=\frac{\sigma_b^2+\sigma_b^4/\sigma_a^2}{(1+\sigma_b^2/\sigma_a^2)^2}=\frac{1/\sigma_b^2+1/\sigma_a^2}{(1/\sigma_b^2+1/\sigma_a^2)^2}=\frac{1}{1/\sigma_a^2+1/\sigma_b^2}$$
as expected.

Comment: thanks a lot for the clear answer!